# OOP Tactics with the Angular MVC Framework?

Tags: angularjs, oop, model-view-controller, model, controller

I learned a lot from reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548100/object-oriented-approach-with-angularjs) that is a question pretty similar to mine. This is my first attempt at OOP, I've always coded using the procedural paradigm. Before I ask my question it would probably be useful to know the context in the form of the stack I'm using.

**Server:** Debian Linux
**Server-Side-Language:** NodeJS with the Express Framework
**DB:** Indirectly MongoDB; actually BAAS in the form of Firebase.

Since we're using BAAS, the only function of NodeJS is to serve the files. In fact, we don't even have a template engine installed. On the front end we're using Angular. The entire site is a real-time SPA that uses Angular routes.

What I'm wondering is how to apply OOP to an MVC framework which is without a real way to create classes or instances of classes. From the question I linked at the beginning of my question, the answer seems to be using angular factories as classes.

Each Angular module is essentially a giant object that should contain it's own MVC application, as far as I understand. What I'm **wondering is how thin the controllers should be**.

With Ruby On Rails a developer is highly encouraged to create a fat model and thin controllers.

The way I *feel* I should go about this is the following:

**1)** Create a model and pack it with classes in the form of Factories.
**2)** Create controllers which create instances of these factories, manipulate and call methods of these factories, and create a feed for the view.
**3)** Create a view which displays the data served by the controllers, via two-way data binding.

The problem that I'm having here is that everywhere I look people are talking about **keeping your controllers thin**. As I'm new to OOP and MVC, I'm sure that I'm not applying the concepts of one or both correctly.

Does my approach follow both OOP and MVC concepts correctly? If not, where am I mistaken, and what is the correct application of these concepts for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't try to compare ruby-on-rails controllers and angular controllers, they have different purpose and responsibilities.

In the server-side framework (not only ROR), the controller is responsible for *incoming requests handling* and usually does this:

- Extract the input data from the request
- Validate the input
- Pass input to some business logic object (may be a model or special object implementing some requirements)
- Format the response (generate the HTML template, convert to json, etc)

That is a lot, so you need to try to move every of these steps to separate objects and try to keep the controller thin.

By the way, making the model fat is also a mistake. Any *fat* class violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

The general advice is to split out your business logic into small objects and keep it as independent from the framework as possible. This way it will be much easier to modify, maintain and test your code.

Now if you look at the angular controller, it handles *the user interface* (the view) and is responsible for:

- Triggering the data loading process from the server
- Reacting to user actions in the UI
- Validating the data entered by the user
- Sending the modified data back to the server

These responsibilities have very little in common with ROR controllers.

Also there is an idea to think of angular.js not as of MVC-framework, but as of [MVW](https://plus.google.com/+AngularJS/posts/aZNVhj355G2) (Model - View - Whatever).

Again, it is better to keep your business logic separated from the framework as much as possible.
And you still need to keep your controllers and all other objects thin.

Here are some ways to do this in angular:

- Split big controllers into smaller, more specific one
- Convert small specific controllers into directives
- Wrap the data and loading / updating process into services
- Move out anything you can into small plain objects, use them from services / factories / directives / controllers

Actually, some people recommend not to use controllers at all and use directives instead: [How I've Improved My Angular Apps by Banning ng-controller](http://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html) and [Die Controllers Die!](http://ng-learn.org/2014/11/Writing_Applications_Without_Controllers/).

If you want to make an application in OPP-way then don’t concentrate much on the framework itself, instead try to follow the general [OOP principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).